# Command `bundle` unrecognized. Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am currently upgrading to the most recent version of react from 0.11.0 branch.

I have upgraded successfully through each step with minimal issues but when I got to 0.14.0 I hit some issues with:

`node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh`

No matter what I do all my machines seem to get this same error.

`` Command `bundle` unrecognized. Did you mean to run this inside a react-native project? ``

I also run this same command that script runs from my terminal in the same location and it works fine, I have also set the path as well and before the script runs no mas, set path inside the script still nothing.

I am hoping someone else has saw this and has found a solution or is there a work around so we dont need this script.

I started this project with react-native ~0.6.0 maybe even a little earlier.

I have even removed nvm to combat this issue and using single install of node which is on `PATH` in both conditions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the latest version of react-native-cli globally?

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: It's something to do with nvm; see groping-in-the-dark at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3938

Answer (score 0):

I personally preferred to install it as a dev dependency.

```
yarn add -D react-native-cli
```